# Is there any downside to using __weak in non-ARC iOS Objective-C code?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios

I'm writing iOS Objective-C code sans ARC. I prefer

```
__weak MyClass *myWeakIVar;
```

to, e.g.

```
MyClass *myWeakIvar; // weak
```

Not only does it read better to me, but if I ever use this code on a garbage-collected platform, etc., I get the benefits of the __weak directive. Are there any downsides to this? Put another way, is it presently equivalent (again, w/o ARC) to a noop on iOS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/280726-weak-references-in-non-gc.html), `__weak` does nothing on iOS if ARC is disabled.

Comment: Correct, but I would still recommend the pattern as the compiler may someday be able to use that for something.

Comment: Now with the ARC compiler, __weak and __strong have meaning in iOS.